# Should I use Infinitive or Gerund?

Tags: word-choice, infinitive-vs-gerund

> Sentences conveying confident intentions produced by Chinese speakers are
>   unlikely ________ the attitudes of friendly or hostile.

**1**.show **2**. to show **3**. showing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Jason. 'to show' would be correct.

However, just to add, I would change the sentence structure at the end. It sounds a bit quirky.

Sentences conveying confident intentions produced by Chinese speakers are unlikely to show friendly or hostile attitudes.

Your sentence is technically correct but sometimes uneccesarry prepositions make a sentence longer than needed.

Answer (score 1):

*...unlikely to show the attitudes of friendly or hostile.*

The phrase *to show* is called [the infinitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive).